# Can't reopen jobs saved with a TSalesforceConnection component

Tags: salesforce, talend

on a new installation of Talend, when I add a TSalesforceConnection component (or any Salesforce component) in my job, then save and close the job, I get an error :

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
> Class listed in @type [org.talend.components.api.properties.ComponentReferenceProperties$ReferenceType] is not found

My vm is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\server\jvm.dll`

I checked the JAVA_HOME env `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2`

Don't know how to deal with this issue...

Comment: I tried to switch to java 11 (zulu) and to install in c:\TOS, no change :(

Comment: Is the tSalesforceConnection available in the palette?

Comment: Yes it is, I can add it to the designer, with a tSalesforceInput and a TLogRow, then I can run the job but it's like I didn't add anything, the job runs, inits the main class, and exits doing nothing... that's weird...

Comment: if I replace the tSalesforceInput  with a tFileInputDelimited I can close and reopen the job, but my tLogRow doesn't outpout anything either :(

Comment: Tried to install on another computer, installed zulu 11 then TOS, same behaviour...

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am facing same. I created a job with tSalesforceConnection and closed it. Now I cannot reopen it.

Comment: @sudarshanKadam No unfortunately I ended installing Talend on a server in cloud, it's still not working on my computer, sorry

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Thanks for replying. What do you do to get data from Salesforce then?

Comment: @SudarshanKadam my install on the windows server has no issue, I get the issue only on my company's computers. I guess it's a conflict with a java install or maybe an app or driver... Couldn't spend more time to search that's why I took a VPS.